# Instance networkInterface had unexpected name: nic0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  name = "test"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "us-west1-b"

  metadata_startup_script = <<EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    echo sdfsdsdf
  EOF

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = "xzxxxxcxvsfsef"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }
}
```

whenever I try to modify the config (to change metadata) i get this error:

> Instance networkInterface had unexpected name: nic0

Comment: do you want to remove/create a network_interface from a existing instance ? because that's not possible: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#limitations I don't really know if that is what is happening on your case

Comment: this happens when a modify the metadata

Comment: didn't get problem when adjust metadata. Which terraform version are you running with?

Comment: getting the same on 0.11.14

Comment: Adding `  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["network_interface"]
  }
`
helped

Comment: This error present in the google Terraform provider, since version 2.1.0.